# Numpy arrays used in training in TF1--Keras have much lower accuracy in TF2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I had a neural net in keras that performed well. Now with the deprecation that came with Tensorflow 2 I had to rewrite the model. Now it is giving me worse accuracy metrics.

My suspicion is that tf2 wants you to use their data structure to train models and they give a example of how to go from Numpy to tf.data.Dataset [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy).

So I did:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_deleted_nans, y_train_no_nans))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_CONST).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Once the training starts I get this warning error:

```
2019-10-04 23:47:56.691434: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Out of range: End of sequence
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
```

Comment: I'm also getting this error. I read on Github (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32817) that it was a bug that got fixed, but which has come back.

Comment: Thanks I just posted there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending `.repeat()` to the creation of my `tf.data.Dataset` solved my error. Like suggested by duysqubix in his eloquent solution posted here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32817#issuecomment-539200561